# Can i expand conditions to if in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to expand condition if checkbox is checked is it possible?

```
string Condition= "A==B"  
if (chechbox1.Checked==true)  
{  
    Condition+="&& B==C";  
}  
if (chechbox2.Checked==true)  
{  
    Condition+="&& C==D";  
}  
if (Condition)  
{  
    //do something  
}
```

Comment: Why not just `if (A == B && checkbox1.Checked && checkbox2.Checked)` ?

Comment: because i have a lot of checkbox and it will be a lot of variation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use boolean logic:

```
bool Condition = A == B;  
if (chechbox1.Checked)  
{  
    Condition &= B == C;  
}  
if (chechbox2.Checked)  
{  
    Condition &= C == D;  
}  

if (Condition)  
{  
    //do something  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using strings, but there's no reason you can't do this directly:

```
bool Condition = (A == B);
if (chechbox1.Checked)  
{  
    Condition = Condition && (B == C);
}  
if (chechbox2.Checked)  
{  
    Condition = Condition && (C == D);  
}  
if (Condition)  
{  
    //do something  
}
```

Comment: Almost good but what if i havent got start condition value, then the final will be: && (B==C) && (C==D) how can i remove && from the begining

Comment: Just use a start value of `true`.